# How can I make this navigation bar using css?

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

I have designed this navigation bar in Photoshop and am lost as to how I could convert it to a pure css navigation bar, would anyone have any ideas ?

TIA.

[image: Navigation Bar Image]

[Link to bigger image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/243540/navbar-round.jpg)

Comment: Minor details: do you want the bar to be fixed-width, or stretch with the page? If the latter, should the search box grow as well, or just float off to the left or right? You can probably find a bunch of comparable solutions by Googling for "horizontal navigation drop down" or something similar.

Comment: Do you mind if we use javascript? I can think of a way to do it with pure CSS, but it is very hacky.

Comment: The navigation bar is fixed width on the page. I dont have anything against javascript except for the fact I wouldn't know how to like modify or code it from scratch (dont know alot about it as yet).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [web designer wall](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/css-gradient-dropdown.html), it has one of the best examples of pure css drop-down menus I've ever seen (view source to see the css code).  With some minor modification to the colors & styles you should be able to re-create your design.

Answer (score 1):

Its not fully complete, I ran out of time to work on the dropdown or add the search, but it should be a significant step in the right direction:

CSS:

```
nav { 
            display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:978px; height:53px; 
            border-bottom:1px solid #abd2f9; border-top:1px solid #f0f9fe; border-left:1px solid #d1e7fc; border-right:1px solid #d1e7fc;
            -webkit-border-radius:20px; -moz-border-radius:20px; border-radius:20px;
            background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(238,248,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(207,234,253,1)));
            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(238,248,255,1), rgba(207,234,253,1) 100%);
            background:linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,248,255,1), rgba(207,234,253,1) 100%);
        }
        nav ul {
            display:block; margin:0; padding:0 45px; list-style:none;
        }
        nav ul li {
            float:left; display:block; margin:0; padding:0;
        }
        nav ul li a { 
            display:block; margin:0 16px 0 0; padding:0 16px; height:53px; line-height:53px; color:#444; text-decoration:none;
        }
        nav ul li a:hover {
            background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(207,234,253,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(238,248,255,1)));
            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(207,234,253,1), rgba(238,248,255,1) 100%);
            background:linear-gradient(top, rgba(207,234,253,1), rgba(238,248,255,1) 100%);
        }

        nav ul li ul {
            display:none; padding:0;
        }
        nav ul li ul li {
            float:none;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for above code, it has give me something to work with, just have to figure out how to work the dropdown menus/search, thanks!

Comment: Question: @Jonathan Based off this above code when I place it on the website the dropdown which I have created using the following code `code`nav li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
            background: #e8f6fd
        }`code` the content on the website moved out the way when the menu drops down, is there a fix for that ?

Comment: First on "nav ul {" selector add "position:relative;" and then on the selector you added "nav li:hover > ul" add "position:absolute;" This takes the dropdown out of the flow of the document and therefore will not push down the content below.

Comment: Thanks again, is the code I implimented correct in the best way to show the dropdown ? Also I am wanting to remove the background colour on the links in that menu and add a 'on' state when that link is the current one being viewed. Thanks again for your assistance.